# Is it true that a full and faithful functor is an embedding iff it reflects identities?

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

I am currently reading category theory from the book [The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf). In exercise 3H(d) (page 45) we are required to show that an equivalence is an embedding if and only if it reflects identities (i.e. if $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be two categories and $F:\mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{B}$ be a functor such $F(k)$ is an identity then
$k$ must be an identity).

However, I have shown the following,

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be two categories and $F:\mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{B}$ be a functor. If $F$ is full and faithful then $F$ is an embedding iff it reflects identities.
>
> *Proof.* To prove that $F$ is an embedding we need to show that $F$ is injective on morphisms. So let $\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}A @>{f}>> B\end{CD}$ and $\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}C @>{g}>> D\end{CD}$ be two $\mathbf{A}$-morphisms such that $F(f)=F(g)$. Since $F(f)=F(g)$ it follows that $F(A)=F(C)$ and $F(B)=F(D)$. Now consider the $\mathbf{B}$-hom-set $\text{Hom}(F(A),F(C))$ then note that the identity map $\text{id}_{F(A)}\in \text{Hom}(F(A),F(C))$. Hence by Proposition 3.31 (page 35) we conclude that there exists an unique $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}A @>{h}>> C\end{CD}$ such that $F(h)=\text{id}_{F(A)}$. Since $F$ reflects identities, it follows that $h$ must be an identity morphism. Consequently $A=C$. Similarly we can show that $B=D$.
>
> Thus we have, $\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}A @>{f}>> B\end{CD}$ and $\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}A @>{g}>> B\end{CD}$. Consider the following map, $$F|_{\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)}:\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)\to \operatorname{Hom}(F(A),F(B))$$Since $f,g\in \operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$, $F(f)=F(g)$ and $F$ is faithful, it follows that $f=g$. So $F$ is an embedding.
>
> Conversely, let $F$ be a full an faithful functor which is an embedding. Let for some $\mathbf{A}$-morphism $\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}A @>{f}>> B\end{CD}$ there exists some $\mathbf{B}$-object such that $\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}C @>{F(f)}>> C\end{CD}$ is an identity morphism in $\mathbf{B}$. Consequently we have, $$F(A)=C=F(B)$$Since $F$ is embedding and hence injective on objects (Remark 3.28, page 34), it follows that $A=B$. Now onsider the following map, $$F|_{\operatorname{Hom}(A,A)}:\operatorname{Hom}(A,A)\to \operatorname{Hom}(C,C)$$Since $f, \operatorname{id}_{A}\in \operatorname{Hom}(A,A)$, $F(f)=F(\operatorname{id}_{A})$ and $F$ is faithful, it follows that $f=\operatorname{id}_{A}$. So $F$ reflects identities.

### Question

Is my proof correct?

Comment: See also [this conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/conversation/functor).

Comment: Yes, it's correct. $\ $

Comment: How did we make use of the assumption that $F$ is full in the converse? I only see properties of an embedding functor.